# Time zone problem on a calculated field

Tags: qfield, datetime

I have configured a date/time field with the default value "now ()" on a shapefile.
When I create an object in QGIS, the datetime is correct. In QField, there is a 2 hour lag. However, the tablet is in the correct time zone.

I don't understand where I can configure that. Is it a bug?